# Is it correct to say to your child "you go to school tomorrow" when that event is a part of a school time-table?

Tags: tense, present-tense, future-tense

We often use the simple present tense to talk about scheduled future event.

For example, *The train leaves at 6 AM tomorrow*.

Children go to school according to a fixed timetable that is set up by their school depending on the schedule.

Is it correct to say to your child "**you go to school tomorrow**" when that event is a part of a school time-table or she is scheduled to go to school tomorrow?

I don't know why not many native speakers want to answer this question, but I would expect a common expression that native speakers often say in this situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression you ask about,
"You go to school tomorrow."
is normal and idiomatic in response to a question such as
"When do I start school?" or something similar.

You might also say it unprompted by a question, with an explanation:
"Stop playing video games and go to bed. You [have to] go to school tomorrow."
The "have to" is optional. You could also say simply "You have school tomorrow."

Comment: And when do we say "You will go to school tomorrow" as some native speakers suggested.

Comment: You could say that, but it sounds more formal. You might say if for emphasis, for example, if the child says "I don't want to go to school tomorrow!"